# Force closing a server COM which have already active reference

Tags: com, delphi-xe, ole

I built a program using cBuilder, with an oleAuto interface to allow some client to make some simple query to the server com.
I want to close the server when for some reason ( ex. the db connection is lost ) something is wrong and a I need to restart the server.

The problem is that if there are some clients connected through the COM reference I get a dialog that prompt me to confirm that I want to close this application.

Is there some way to avoid the dialog and force the closing of the server?

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously you need to release all references to the object in order to properly close the server.

Were you unaware of that, or is there a reason why you need to hold on to the reference?

Comment: I know I have also to manage correctly the reference to the server com, but I laso want to have an emergency solution to force the shutdown of an application when it has some critical problem.

Comment: Well, that solution should involve releasing all references to all of the server's objects! It's not like it's gonna take a long time to do it. Oh and remember that you should also call CoUninitialize after releasing all references.